# How can I make the interstitial ad appear when the button counter reaches the targeted number?

Tags: java, android, counter, interstitial

When the button counter reaches the targeted clicks, I show an interstitial ad. The interstitial ad was working fine until I left the project for quite a while and today when I returned to it, it wasn't working. I have two different interstitial ads that I want to show on different amounts of clicks, but neither of them are working.

**Home.java**

```
    int countClicksNext = 0;
    int countClicksCopy = 0;
    
    int triggerClicksNav = 7;
    int triggerClicks = 3; 

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
         
         // Ads

        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NotNull LoadAdError adError) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(adError);
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                super.onAdOpened();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                super.onAdClicked();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
            }
        });

 }



    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void next() {
        countClicksNext++;
        position = (position + 1) % quotes_list.size();
        quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
        countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && countClicksNext >= triggerClicksNav) {
           showAd();
        }
    }

   


    private void copy() {
        countClicksCopy++;
        ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", quotesTxt.getText());
        if (clipboardManager != null) {
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && countClicksCopy >= triggerClicks) {
           showAdOth();
        }

    }

   

 private void showAd() {
        mInterstitialAd.show(HomeActivity.this);
        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                mInterstitialAd = null;
                intertitalAd();
              
               countClicksNext = 0;
             
            }
        });
    }
    private void showAdOth() {
        mInterstitialAd.show(HomeActivity.this);
        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                mInterstitialAd = null;
                intertitalAdOth();
                countClicksCopy = 0;
                
            }
        });
    }

    public void intertitalAd() {

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


        InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });

    }
    public void intertitalAdOth() { 

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


        InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: What's the error code in logcat? please add your logcat errors

Comment: there are no errrors

Comment: Ok, I deleted the interstialAd() from the onCreate, but after adding it back, the ads appear again

Comment: It's recommended to add ads codes in onStart or onViewCreated if you used fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is my old app I implemented InterstitialAd on it**

first, create two vars one for interstitial ad and the other to store the number of the clicks

```
private static byte clickNumber = 0;
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
```

second in onCreate prepare the advertisement

```
interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

the ad method shows the ad when the targeted click is reached e.g 3 clicks

```
  public static void detailsActivityInterstitial(){
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                if(clickNumber == 3){
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }else {
                    clickNumber++;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                Log.e("onAdFailedToLoad","detailsActivityInterstitial" + errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                clickNumber = 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                clickNumber = 0;

            }
        });
    }
```

and finally, call the method in `onStart` method when user is connected

```
 if(Utils.hasNetworkAccess(this)) {
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.ADMOB_APP_ID));
detailsActivityInterstitial();
}
```

Also, there are [**Google sample ads**](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples) on GitHub for every type of AdMob ads, you can use it as a reference, the following one is for interstitial, It simulates the display of an ad in a game

the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/impossible_game"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/game_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/retry_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Retry" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity class

```
/**
 * Main Activity. Inflates main activity xml.
 */
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long GAME_LENGTH_MILLISECONDS = 3000;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private Button retryButton;
    private boolean gameIsInProgress;
    private long timerMilliseconds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        // Log the Mobile Ads SDK version.
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Mobile Ads SDK Version: " + MobileAds.getVersion());

        // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
        });

    loadAd();

        // Create the "retry" button, which tries to show an interstitial between game plays.
        retryButton = findViewById(R.id.retry_button);
        retryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        retryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showInterstitial();
            }
        });

        startGame();
    }

  public void loadAd() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    InterstitialAd.load(
        this,
        AD_UNIT_ID,
        adRequest,
        new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
            // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
            // an ad is loaded.
            MyActivity.this.interstitialAd = interstitialAd;
            Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "onAdLoaded()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
                new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                    // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                    // show it a second time.
                    MyActivity.this.interstitialAd = null;
                    Log.d("TAG", "The ad was dismissed.");
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                    // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                    // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                    // show it a second time.
                    MyActivity.this.interstitialAd = null;
                    Log.d("TAG", "The ad failed to show.");
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                    Log.d("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
                  }
                });
          }

          @Override
          public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            // Handle the error
            Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
            interstitialAd = null;

            String error =
                String.format(
                    "domain: %s, code: %d, message: %s",
                    loadAdError.getDomain(), loadAdError.getCode(), loadAdError.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(
                    MyActivity.this, "onAdFailedToLoad() with error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
          }
        });
  }

    private void createTimer(final long milliseconds) {
        // Create the game timer, which counts down to the end of the level
        // and shows the "retry" button.
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }

        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 50) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUnitFinished) {
                timerMilliseconds = millisUnitFinished;
                textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + ((millisUnitFinished / 1000) + 1));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                gameIsInProgress = false;
                textView.setText("done!");
                retryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // Start or resume the game.
        super.onResume();

        if (gameIsInProgress) {
            resumeGame(timerMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // Cancel the timer if the game is paused.
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and restart the game.
    if (interstitialAd != null) {
      interstitialAd.show(this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ad did not load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startGame();
        }
    }

    private void startGame() {
    // Request a new ad if one isn't already loaded, hide the button, and kick off the timer.
    if (interstitialAd == null) {
      loadAd();
        }

        retryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        resumeGame(GAME_LENGTH_MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private void resumeGame(long milliseconds) {
        // Create a new timer for the correct length and start it.
        gameIsInProgress = true;
        timerMilliseconds = milliseconds;
        createTimer(milliseconds);
        countDownTimer.start();
    }
}
```

This video from the Google Admob channel shows [**the Best practices to win with AdMob interstitial ads**](https://youtu.be/Ccrj8D0m1KA)